# How to check if jQuery UI files have been included?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a CMS on my website and have run into a problem. The CMS includes jQuery files on some pages, but not on all, and I need to be able to use jQuery everywhere. I found a solution for including the base jQuery library by using the following code:

```
if(!window.jQuery) 
{
    document.write("<" + "script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></" + "script>");
}
```

However, I don't know how to check whether the jQuery UI JS and CSS files have been included or not, specifically these files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

Is there a way to check if those files have been included, similar to the above code for the base jQuery library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(!jQuery.ui) 
{
    // Load Jquery UI here
}
```

Remember, you can use jQuery's [getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to load libraries...

Comment: problem with getScript is the cache busting.

Comment: About getScript, what url I can use on my localhost :-? and then, if I change my host, I must change url again, right :-?

Comment: @user1487380 You just use a relative path to your .js file. Try it, it's quite straightforward.

Comment: @epascarello: what is cache busting with getScript :-? can you explain more clearly please ...

Comment: @LeeTaylor - Thanks for your answer. This is kind of unrelated to my original question, but you mention using `getScript()` to load libraries and I'm wondering whether you think that is a better way to load jQuery UI as opposed to using `document.write()`?

Comment: @Nate - It's just that document.write is a little clunky. The end result is much the same.

Comment: @LeeTaylor - Is there any way around using `document.write()` to include the base jQuery library (the way I did in the first code block in my question)?

Comment: @Nate - Just use the script tag

Answer (score 3):

Look for the `ui` property of the jQuery object.

```
if(!window.jQuery.ui)
```